# Receive *.htm file when trying to download apk file from browser?Why?

Tags: android

I am creating an android app that is *.apk (.apk is the extention of the file after creating)file and uploaded that file in server.. after downloading that file from server into my mobile i am getting *.htm (.htm is the extention of the file after downloading) why?

Comment: When you looked at the contents of the "*.htm", what did you learn?

Comment: Does whats in the htm explain?

Comment: content is correct but the extention is wrong. if i change the content after downloading then its works.

Comment: what *server configuration are you working with?

Comment: now i am using apache server in linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly got the sollution:

putting this in my apache/ mime.types:

```
application/vnd.android.package-archive     apk
```

### or

if you are using python you can put this line in settings.py:-

```
import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type("application/vnd.android.package-archive",".apk", True)
```